# Error doing face recognition with CIDetectorTypeFace

Tags: ios, swift, face-detection, core-image

I have set up a CIDetector that worked great in a sample app that I tried. But on my current project the features array is always empty.

I have created a custom camera with AVFoundation. I need to detect faces after the still image has been taken.

What am I missing? Any common issues, that you ran into when first using face detection?

Here is the code:

```
var ciImage = CIImage(CGImage: capturedImage!.CGImage)

var ciDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil,

    options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh])

var feautures = ciDetector.featuresInImage(ciImage)

for feautures: CIFaceFeature in (feautures as! [CIFaceFeature]) {

    self.faceCount++
    print("face detected")

}
```

Thanks

Comment: The problem was the orientation.

Comment: can you tell me how i can  compare 2 Faces ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you're using the same variable name for your collection and the iterated item ("feautures"). Also, no need to wrap the typecast in brackets nor to specify the type twice.

Here's a working version:

```
let ciImage = CIImage(CGImage: capturedImage!.CGImage)

let ciDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh])

let features = ciDetector.featuresInImage(ciImage)

for face in features as! [CIFaceFeature] {

    self.faceCount++
    print("face detected")

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i am still getting the same results . The code works fine in another sample application that i downloaded, but not in my current app.  So the code is fine, but i can't pin point where the issue is. The image looks fine and the detector should be working but isn't.

Comment: You're welcome. This is weird indeed because the code works (tested in a Playground). No idea why it doesn't work in your project. I'll update if I find something.

Comment: Yeah this really has bogged me down. I can't seem to find the issue especially since this is my first time using face detection. Thanks man.